# Equality operator versus bitwise AND operator usage

Tags: c, equality, bitwise-and

In C language, I often see `if` statements in such form:

```
#define STATUS 0x000A
UINT16 InterruptStatus;
if (InterruptStatus & STATUS)
{
 <do something here....>
}
```

If I had this statement, would it be any different in processing time or any other reason why this would not be the preferred/alternative way?

```
#define STATUS 0x000A
UINT16 InterruptStatus;
if (InterruptStatus == STATUS)
{
 <do something here....>
}
```

Comment: Is `InterruptStatus` supposed to be a bit-field? Or should it contain just a single value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, they are **not** the same.

In case of a [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND), two *different* values of operands can produce a `true`, whereas for [equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator#Standard_relational_operators), both must be same.

Consider decimal value `5` and `3` as operands.

- Bitwise AND will produce a TRUE value for condition check ( `5 & 3 == 1`).
- Equality will produce a FALSE value (`5 ==3 ==> false`)

So they are not alternatives, really.

Bitwise operations are widely used to check a particular bit of a *flag* variable to be "set" or "unset".

Comment: Off-topic but bitwise XOR may relatively often be encountered as an (inverted) comparison.

Answer (score 2):

This can be used for checking if some number has some bits set or not, so it is different from equality.

Assume you have some number represented in binary as `0b00010001`

And you want to check if bit number 4 is set, so you need to do

```
if(0b00010001 & 0b00010000)
 // do something.
```

So not necessarily the two numbers above are equal - however, using above check you can verify if 4th bit is set on the 0b00010001 number.

Comment: It is used in an interesting context when an interrupt is being read from an FPGA register. From what I understand the authors intent may have been to trigger when any interrupt fires at bit position 1 or 3 ( 0x000A ), albeit counter intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

`&` is a `bitwise AND` operator. It is used to check if a bit at a certain position is on or not.

`==` is an `equality` operator which returns true only if the values of both operands match exactly.

For more on operators in C: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Answer (score 0):

Top one will be logically true if any one of the bit matches, 0x000A. it doesn't have to exactly equal 0x000A; it could be true if

```
if ((InterruptStatus == 0x0008) || (InterruptStatus == 0x0002))
```

The bottom code makes sure it is absolutely equal to 0x000A.

Comment: "it could be true if..." not only that, it also ignores the status of the other bits. IOW, it's true even if e.g. `InterruptStatus==0x28`.

Answer (score 0):

Both are different.

== is a relational operator

& is a bit wise operator

From [tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm):

> **==** : Checks if the values of two operands are `equal` or not. If yes, then the condition becomes `true`.
>
> **&** : Binary AND Operator copies a bit to the result if it exists in both operands.

For example:

A= 12 , B =13

A == B: produces output as false as these two are different

A & B:  Output will be true

A = 0000 1100

B = 0000 1101

A&B = 0000 1100 -> which is 12 and it is a valid integer.so condition will be true

Comment: Who is asking about logical AND here?

Comment: @SouravGhosh It is a mistake. I was about to edit it

Comment: Removed downvote. A suggestion: Try to improve the content as well as formatting to make it easier to read and understand.

Comment: Having said, I will try to follow your suggestion